# SoftInputMode cannot be set to hidden

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I created an Activity with a Dialog theme and it has an EditText.
I don't want to show soft input on every activity so I used the following code on that activity:

```
 EditText editTextData=GetView(R.id.txtData);
    editTextPin.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(editTextData, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

This makes the input keyboard visible.
After the input, I tried to make it hidden with this code:

```
 InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(editTextData.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

It remains visible. What else should I call?

Answer (score 0):

try ..

> mgr.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(editTextData.getWindowToken(),
>   1);

or

try

> InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
>         Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextData.getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: Unfortunately it is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to hide the keyboard..

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity act) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) act.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(act.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: Unfortunately it is still visible.